# $(X,Y,Z)$ is a random normal vector. Compute $\text{Var}(X\cdot Y).$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> $(X,Y,Z)$ is a random vector with the following density function:
>   $$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{56\pi^3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{(x+1)^2}{7}+y^2+5(z-2)^2+4y(z-2)\right]}$$
>
> What is the variance of $X\cdot Y$?

I was able to find that $(\mathbb{E}XY)^2=0$ using the covariance matrix. Is there a similar way to calculate $\mathbb{E}(XY)^2$? Meaning, without actually computing it by definition.

For you convenience, here's the covariance matrix:
$$\left[\matrix{7&0&0\\0&5&-2\\0&-2&1}\right]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent too.
Thus $E(XY)^2 = E[X^2] E[Y^2]$.